# Game download resetting for several times

Tags: steam, war-thunder

I'm trying to install War Thunder in Steam from my Xbuntu 14.04 ... I had to pause the download multiple times to download it in segments. But every 2 or 3 days later it gets reset to the first and the download starts from beginning . How do I download then ?

Comment: What do you mean "had to pause the download multiple times to download it in segments"? Can't you download it in one go?

Comment: My net connection is way too slow to download it in one go, so I have to download it in segments

Comment: How would a slow connection stop that?

Comment: Leaving it download overnight, while at work/school should give you plenty of time to do it.

Comment: Try downloading the non steam version of the game maybe that will work? http://warthunder.com/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam usually resets downloads when an update has been released for a game. War thunder receives updates constantly
there is a partial fix but not sure what the folder name for war thunder should be
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3013670

Comment: You may want to include the relevant parts of the link in case the link ever dies, that way the information may live on.